# Hadoop streaming api: how to remove unwanted delimiters

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Say I have a file on HDFS:

> 1
>   2
>   3

I want it transformed to

> a
>   b
>   c

I wrote a mapper.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print chr(int(line) + ord('a') - 1)
```

then using the streaming api:

> hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar \
>       -mapper mapper.py -file mapper.py -input /input -output /output

But the result in /output is "a\t\nb\t\nc\t\n":

> a\t
>   b\t
>   c\t

note those extra unprintable tab characters, I used '\t' instead. It's documented [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html):

> If there is no tab character in the line, then entire line is considered as key and the value is null.

So the tabs were added by streaming api as separators. But however I modify the separator related options, I can't make it disappear.

Thus my problem is, is there a way to do that job clean, without extra things like tabs?

Or to make it clearer, is there a way to use hadoop just as a *distributed* filter, disgarding its key/value mechanism?

====

update @ 2013.11.27

As I discussed with friends, there's no easy way to achieve the goal, and I made a workaround to this problem by using tabs as field separator in my output, and set tab as field separator in hive as well.

Some of my friends proposed using of `-D mapred.textoutputformat.ignoreseparator=true`, but that parameter just won't work. I investigated into this file:

```
hadoop-1.1.2/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextOutputFormat.java
```

and didn't find the option. But as an alternative solution, streaming api accepts a parameter `-outputformat` which specifies another outputformat.

According to [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat/), you can make a copy of TextOutputFormat.java, remove the default '\t', compile it, and then pack it as a jar, and call streaming api with `-libjars yourjar.jar -outputformat path.to.your.outputformat`. But I didn't succeed this way with hadoop-1.1.2. Just write this down for others' reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of these delimiters by specifying that your job is a map-only job - which is essentially what you want to be a distributed filter and the output of your mapper will be the final output.

To do that in Hadoop streaming, you can use the following option:

```
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0
```

So for the full command this would look something like:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -mapper mapper.py -file mapper.py -input /input -output /output
```

Comment: thanks, but I've already tried this. Just won't work, because the default TextOutputFormat adds tabs.